# Iterate average of n elements per row

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a shape of (2205, 6000) obtained using a sensor with sampling rate 100hz. Each row correspond to a minute cicle (In this case i have 2205 cicles, 6000 samples per minute), but i need to get info for each second.

So, for each row i need to get the mean for the 100 values until the last value of the row (In this case i'll have 60 values per row ) and append it to another df named "Seconds" and do this operation for all de rows.

The [Data](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Arancium98/ucihydraulic/main/Data/PS1.txt)

I think i need to create a double for loop for each row but i don't know how, any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilise `numpy` here, to reshape your dataframe and compute the means efficiently, without a double loop, by frrst reshaping the it so that each second (or each set of 100 readings) has its own row, and then computing the means:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(2205, 6000))

# Reshape the dataframe to have 100 values in each row
reshaped_data = df.values.reshape(-1, 100)

# Compute the mean for each row (or each set of 100 readings)
means = reshaped_data.mean(axis=1)

# Reshape the means to have 60 values for each of the 2205 cycles
Seconds = pd.DataFrame(means.reshape(df.shape[0], -1))
```

With this approach, you avoid writing explicit loops, making the computation much faster especially given the size of your dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

A dataframe in simple terms is a 2D array.
I assume you need the mean of values in chunks of 100 so you will end up with 60 readings after calculating the mean.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
readings = np.random.randn(2205, 6000)
de = pd.DataFrame(readings)
#de your minutes dataframe
#ds dataframe created for seconds
def minute_to_second(de):
#mean function and conversion
    ds=[]
    for i,row in de.iterrows():
        second_list=[]
        for i in range(len(row)):
            if i%100==99:
                second_list.append(row[i-100:i])
        ds.append(second_list)
    return ds

ds=pd.DataFrame(minute_to_second(de))
print(ds)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't necessarily need to use double for loops.

You can take advantage of pandas built-in functions to perform this operation efficiently.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create a random DataFrame 
np.random.seed(0)
data = np.random.randn(2205, 6000)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Function to calculate mean values for each second
def calculate_second_means(row):
    # Split the row into chunks of 100 values (for 100 Hz sampling rate)
    chunks = [row[i:i+100] for i in range(0, len(row), 100)]
    
    # Calculate the mean for each chunk (second)
    mean_values_per_second = [chunk.mean() for chunk in chunks]
    
    return mean_values_per_second

rows = []

# Iterate through each row 
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # Calculate the mean values for each second for a row
    mean_values_per_second = calculate_second_means(row)
    
    # Append the mean values for this row to the list
    rows.append(mean_values_per_second)

# Create the seconds_df DataFrame from the list of rows
seconds_df = pd.DataFrame(rows)

# seconds_df contains the mean values for each second for all rows
seconds_df.columns = [f'Second_{i+1}' for i in range(len(seconds_df.columns))]

# Display result
print(seconds_df)
```